# How to hide element overflow without cropping inline images/text?

Tags: html, css, overflow, crop, hidden

I have a container div with property `overflow: hidden` and a `max-height` of 100px. This container element contains an arbitrary amount of inline elements including both images and stylized text.

Currently, if more than 100px of content is present, then the rest of the content is clipped. This is the general behavior I want, except I keep running into issues where portions of lines of text are clipped (i.e. the bottom half of letters would just be cut off) or half of an image will be cropped out.

I found a workaround to the text issue by manually setting the column-width property, but I cannot find any way to stop the image from being cropped. If any individual line of text or image cannot be rendered in its entirety inside of the container div, I want the entire image/line-of-text to be hidden.

**In summary:** I have a div element that wraps a bunch of inline elements (primarily text and images) and hides any overflow and I want to not display any lines of text or images that it would crop/clip some portions of. I have found a workaround for the text issue, but not for images. How can I achieve my desired functionality?

EDIT: Per commenter request, I am posting my, albeit trivial, code:

HTML:

```
<div id="test">
  <p>
    This is a test. This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.
  </p>
  <img src="https://hackernoon.com/hn-images/0*xMaFF2hSXpf_kIfG.jpg" alt="Girl in a jacket" width="500" height="600">
</div>
```

The inline elements will just be text and images wrapped in the appropriate tags (their actual values are dynamic and change depending on the situation. The content I have provided here is just an example.

CSS:

```
#test { 
  max-height: 200px;
  max-width:200px;
  overflow: hidden; 
}
```

Here is a [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q9n80ze1/) for this example. As you can see, the image gets cropped.

Here is [another JS Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/q9n80ze1/1/) where the text itself gets clipped halfway through the line.

In the first example, I want the image to not be displayed at all.

In the second, I want the last line to not be displayed at all.

Elements that cannot be displayed in their entirety should just not be displayed. I am having particular trouble getting this desired behavior for images, so any help there would be particularly appreciated.

Comment: Please post your code along with the question

Comment: @ChetanNaik I posted the code as you requested. The code is extremely trivial and is spelled out fairly explicitly in the question description which is why I did not originally post it. The question is more of a general design question than a question specific to my implementation which is why I originally deemed it unnecessary to include.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of your text and image elements inside the container `div`? Otherwise we can only guess what you tried to achieve and why it does not work properly.

Comment: @user2779450, please provide more info on what exactly you wanted to achieve with an example code or screenshot.

Comment: @Anji Added some example code and two different examples in JS Fiddle to play around with

Comment: @SparkFountain See the updated example(s)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve the desired behavior using JavaScript. In this snippet I'm just giving "hidden" items a low opacity, for illustration purposes. Obviously, you could simply set the hidden items to `visibility: hidden` or `display: none` in a real-world application.

```js
const containers = document.querySelectorAll('.container');
containers.forEach(container => hideOverflow(container));

// Hide all overflowing images and portions of text nodes
function hideOverflow(container) {
  container.childNodes.forEach(node => {
    if (node.nodeName !== '#text') {
      if (node.nodeName === 'IMG' ||
          node.querySelector('img') != null) {
        // Hide entire image if it overflows
        if (node.offsetTop + node.offsetHeight > container.offsetHeight) {
          node.classList.add('hidden');
        }
      }
      else {
        // Hide overflowing text characters
        if (node.offsetTop > container.offsetHeight) {
          node.classList.add('hidden');
        }
        else {
          hideChildOverflow(node, container);
        }
      }
    }
  });
}

// Find all descendant text nodes, and hide their overflowing characters
function hideChildOverflow(node, container) {
  if (node.nodeName === '#text') {
    const overflow = document.createRange();
    overflow.setEnd(node, node.length);
    
    // Shrink range until it includes only overflowing characters
    for (let i = 0; i <= node.length; i++) {
      overflow.setStart(node, i);
      
      if (overflow.getBoundingClientRect().top > container.offsetHeight) {
        break;
      }
    }
    
    // Hide the overflowing characters
    const span = document.createElement('span');
    span.classList.add('hidden');
    overflow.surroundContents(span);
  }
  else {
    node.childNodes.forEach(childNode => {
      hideChildOverflow(childNode, container);
    });
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  max-height: 200px;
  max-width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.hidden {
  opacity: .2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/50" width="200" height="50" />
  <p>All of this text is visible, since none of it overflows the container.</p>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/100" width="200" height="100" />
  <p>This text is below the container, so it gets hidden.</p>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/100" width="200" height="100" />
  <p>The start of this text is visible, but the last part gets hidden since it overflows the bottom of the container. Any piece of text that overflows, even if only partially, gets hidden.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this correctly then the logic for your component is as follows:

1)If your text and image fit within 200px of height, then display normally.

2)If either the text or the image is too large to fit in the div then do not display one of them.

3)If either the text or the image on their own is too large to fit in the div then do not display either of them.

If that's correct then likely what you'll need to do is involve some kind of javascript.

What you could do is check with javascript what the height of those paragraphs or images are and then conditionally apply some css classes that hide them.

Here's an example with Jquery to check if only the paragraph is too tall:

```
if( $('.one-specific-paragraph').height > 200 ){ $('.one-specific-paragraph').addClass('hide-paragraph)};
```

This is where the css class is something like `.hide-paragraph{display:none;}`

Then do the same thing with the image. You will likely need to do this in a forEach loop or something similar such that it checks every div, rather than just one.

If you wanted to check the height for both the paragraph and the image then you would do a similar if statement to the above example but just add the height of both elements before checking if it's above 200px.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. That isn't quite the behavior I want. If I have a paragraph of text, I only want to clip the lines of text that overflow, not the entire paragraph (but I only want to keep a line if the entire line fits, i.e. I do not clip half of any characters of text). If there is text and an image, if the image overflows what is left of the div, I want to not display it at all instead of just cropping it, if that makes sense. I also do not know exactly how many inline div elements (text or images) are present, that is all added dynamically.